# Convertir una variable javascript en php

Tags: javascript

Tengo una petición ajax y desearía convertir la variable data  de $ajax 
 a formato php

La idea es: Con el resultado de la conversión, después de `success function(agenda)`, cumplimentar el objeto events en el que necesito que las variables esté en formato php. Gracias anticipadas.

envío en código:

Aquí comenzaría la zona del código  que no acabo de afinar.

```
             var dato ={
            ' fecha':$('#input-fecha-agenda').val(),
       "mensaje":$('#input-evento').val(),
           "start":$('#input-desde-agenda').val() ,
             "end": $('#end').val(),
             "title":$('#input-titulo').val(),
      "todoeldia":$('#input-todoeldia').val(),
        "_token" : $("#_token").val() 
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: {"dato" : dato},
                dataType: 'json',
                url:'/agendas/insert',
                success: function (agenda) {
                    events:[
                    ]    
                }

            });      
      }
});

});


</script>
<?php
                $var = $_POST['dato'];
                //Procedimiento a realizar

?>
```

Comment: A ver, cuando haces una petición Ajax, en el `success` recibes lo que **acaba de volver desde el servidor**. Es absurdo querer volver al servidor desde el `success`, justo porque acabas de volver de allí. Es como si viajas a Australia, constándote el billeto 3,000 dólares. Y al llegar a Australia te tienes que comprar  otro billete de 3,000 dólares o más para traer algo que olvidaste antes de salir. ¡Trae todo lo que tengas que traer, haz todo lo que tengas que hacer antes de salir y cuando llegues a Australia (`success`) abre la maleta y trabaja con lo que trajiste!. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Cuando desde el servidor ,vuelve a success  después de haber actualizado la tabla ,sale del controller. php como: return json_encode($agendas); :     e ingresa a agenda.index en  javascript ,ese mismo objeto he de tratarlo en events en php para actualizar la vista de agenda ,tengo una entrada javascript que he de tratar en php,voy a Australia sin saber ingles y con pesetas en el bolsillo.

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso haces otra petición. 
Sobre la marcha no se puede "compartir" variables entre el frontend y el backend. Lo que sí puede haber es comunicación como lo que has hecho. En ese sentido si quieres que en cierto momento envíe un dato necesario al servidor entonces tendrías que hacer otra request al servidor.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ,tienes toda la razón